# how to get list of users in a role in asp.net identity web forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2 in web forms and i need to get list of a role users, i mean list of users that are in `"Admin"` role or `"User"` role.
can you help me?

Comment: Does this issue solved? I'm aslo looking for to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Roles IQueryable on the RoleManager class -- it's meant to allow queries. If you're using EF, then the Roles is `IQueryable<IdentityRole>` and IdentityRole has a collection of Users property. With these IDs you can then access the Users IQueryable on the UserManager. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Brock Allen .
i found that i should change some base codes in role manager and user manager system in asp.net identity, if some one needs to change and customize asp.net identity here is a good article : [click](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/13/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-Roles.aspx)